# Convert tensorflow tf.Variable to numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I am trying to convert Tensorflow variable to either numpy array or list of lists to be iterated in external python function which I don't want to modify for a reason:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

v = tf.Variable(np.array([[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4]]),dtype=tf.float32)

def numpy_func(x):
    new_v = []
    for v1 in v:
        print(v1)
        new_v.append(v1)
    return new_v


init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)

    v1 = tf.Variable(numpy_func(np.array(v.eval())),dtype=tf.float32)
```

This returns me `TypeError: 'Variable' object is not iterable.` because `tf.Variable` is still transferred to the function. I tried to convert it to tensor, but it also leaves `tf.Variable` intact:

```
v1 = tf.Variable(numpy_func(np.array(tf.convert_to_tensor(v,dtype=tf.float32).eval())),dtype=tf.float32)

TypeError: 'Variable' object is not iterable.
```

What should I do? I want to have pythonic list or numpy array, not tensorflow object.

PS. A workaround is to modify a function with something like

```
for i in range(0,v.shape[0]):
    v1 = v[i,:].eval()
```

But I don't want to do it, because I expect to call pythonic function from different places.

Comment: Could you please try following :
session = tf.Session()
session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

Comment: @AhmetTavli I think what I have here is equivalent.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't want the for loop to be `for v1 in x`? otherwise, your function does not depend on its input. Also, I think you need to switch the last line to `v1 = tf.Variable(np.array(numpy_func(v.eval())),dtype=tf.float32)`

Comment: @Lior Oh, I'm sorry! I was simplifying much bigger function and didn't notice that I'm calling variable from inside.

Comment: @Lior Thanks, now it works!

Comment: @Lior I will .eval() all the variables needed within a session and pass them into function.